# Blazor Server Authentication not working after publishing to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-identity

I am creating a Blazor Server app and Implemented Authentication using Identity Server.
Everything was working fine until I published it to Azure. Everything is working except Login & Register which return
"Sorry, there's nothing at this address."

When I click Login Azure log stream shows this exception

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(PageContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateModelFactory>b__0(PageContext pageContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

and Register:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Security.SecurityException: Invalid assembly public key. (0x8013141E)
at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.get_Signature()
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.get_PropertyType()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultPageApplicationModelProvider.CreateModel(PageActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, TypeInfo pageTypeInfo)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultPageApplicationModelProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(PageApplicationModelProviderContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageLoader.LoadAsyncCore(PageActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageLoaderMatcherPolicy.ApplyAsyncAwaited(CandidateSet candidates, Task`1 actionDescriptorTask, Int32 index)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatch|8_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

and my startup page is:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddTransient<IDisplayMessage, DisplayMessage>();
        services.AddServices();
        services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationStateService, AuthenticationStateServiceServerSide>();

        services.AddAuthentication();

        services.AddDbContextPool<MainDbContext>(options => options
           .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
           .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
           .UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString(db), mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions
           .ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 19), ServerType.MySql)));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        })
            .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MainDbContext>();

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<ApplicationUser>>();

        var assemlies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("LaWeb")).Select((item) => Assembly.Load(item)).ToList();
        assemlies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddAutoMapper(assemlies);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

It works perfectly when runnning from visual studio or when publishing localy to a folder and then running using cmd...

Comment: I'm going through the same situation and I still haven't been able to find out why. have you discovered anything yet?

Comment: We are seeing the System.Security.SecurityException: Invalid assembly public key. (0x8013141E) today after publishing a .NET Core API service to Azure. If anyone has helpful hints that may help resolve the issue, please post something here.

Comment: After months of trying to find solution I ended up creating my own full Blazor Login system. Based on on the code of the scaffolded pages and this comment here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13601#issuecomment-679870698 for server-side. I think in client its easier